# how to wait for API response before executing code in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I have to wait for data from an API to set value of a variable and use it in a if condition.

The problem is i'm not clear how to wait for the data using async and await.
I tried a few things below is the code .

```
currentObj.isObjEditable = this.isObjEditable(obj);

async isObjEditable(obj: any) {
    if (this.isContentEditable === undefined) {
      let test = await this.getsocialMediaData();
      console.log(test);

    }
    else {
      if (this.isContentEditable) {
        if (some Condition1 )
          return true;
        else if (condition2)
          return true;
        else if (condition 3)
          return true;
        else {
          return false;
        }

      }
      else
        return false;
    }

async getsocialMediaData() {

      this.commonService.getSocialMediaSettings().subscribe(value=> {
       return value;
     });

  }

getSocialMediaSettings(){

 return Observable.timer(0, 60000)
            .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }))
            .map(res => res.json());

}
```

when i log test it returns a promise.The value of isContentEditable is set from the data received from the API.

I know what i have done is not correct but i also dont know how to correct this or what is the right approach.

Please Guide

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the async-await does not work with observables, but only with promises. In your `getsocialMediaData()` function you are using an observable subscribe call which should resolve your value. That doesn't work with `await`. Here's a description of what `await` is doing ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)):

> If a Promise is passed to an await expression, it waits for the Promise to be fulfilled and returns the fulfilled value. [...] If the value is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved Promise, and waits for it.

This is the reason why your log returns a promise, the function that you are using here is not returning a promise, so it just creates one.

Now the trick that we can do here should be simple (but also not 100% clean, I should note that). Instead of subscribing to the observable inside of your `getSocialMediaData()` function, we can just create a promise from it and return this promise. Also the function here does not have to be `async` anymore, only the one where `await` is called inside. Here's what it could look like.

```
// this has to be async, so that it pauses on an await call
async isObjEditable(obj: any) {
  if (this.isContentEditable === undefined) {
    let test = await this.getsocialMediaData();
    console.log(test);
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
  else
    return false;
}

// this does not have to be async anymore
function getsocialMediaData() {
  // here we make a promise out of the observable and RETURN it
  return this.commonService.getSocialMediaSettings().toPromise();
  // this will return the fullfilled value
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) you can find more about async and await. Hope this helps.